# Python скрапинг

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Хеллоу, форумчане.
Каким образом достать процент из класса 'sorted'?
[image: нужно достать 55.23%]

пробовал так, но возвращается пустой список.

```
soup = s.find_all('td', class_ = 'sorted')
```

Comment: soup = s.find('td', class_ = 'sorted').text не работает?

Comment: нет, не работает, пустая строка

Comment: может тут ответ найдёте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377533/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-table

Comment: Ссылку на сайт скиньте.

Comment: Винрейты вытащить . 
https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/winning